# What does "when it should take one" mean?

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

> "We need to really speed up planning and consent for renewables and
> for network connections and for vehicle charging," says Emma
> Pinchbeck, the chief executive of trade association Energy UK.

> "It takes 12 years to build a wind farm in this country, **when it
> should take one.**

This is a quote from BBC (https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-64440827).  I don't what "when it should take one" means here.  What does this "one" stand for?  Is this an idiomatic expression?

Answer (score 3):

It means "when it should take one year".

This would be obvious in speech, because "one" would be stressed; but it's not so obvious in writing.

Comment: Agreed -  The stress pattern has to be understood to make sense of the sentence.  "It takes **12** years, when it should take **one**.   The expression is idiomatic. - E.g. "These curtains took 10 metres of fabric when they should only have taken 8."

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  The meaning would be abvious if "one" is stressed, indeed.